# Artifactory: how can I obtain a complete dump of all fields for an artifact?

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm interested in the value of one field (Module ID) but there seems to be no way of obtaining this specifically. A complete dump of all field values would also suffice but I haven't succeeded in finding a way to do that either. I've looked at and tried the searches available within the documentation here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SEARCHES

If it helps, I'm trying to query an on-premise installation of Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

More fields can be added to the AQL using the "include" element.

For example - to list all artifacts under "libs-release-local" repository, including their module names, run the following query:

```json
items.find(
    {
        "repo":{"$eq":"libs-release-local"}
    }
).include("artifact.module")
```

Response example:

```json
{
    "results": [
        {
            "repo": "libs-release-local",
            "path": "org/jfrog/test/multi2/2.17.0",
            "name": "multi2-2.17.0.jar",
            "type": "file",
            "size": 1022,
            "created": "2021-09-11T13:51:33.878Z",
            "created_by": "deployer",
            "modified": "2021-09-11T13:51:33.631Z",
            "modified_by": "deployer",
            "updated": "2021-09-11T13:51:33.881Z",
            "artifacts": [
                {
                    "modules": [
                        {
                            "module.name": "org.jfrog.test:multi2:2.17.0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can find all of the required information under [AQL documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language).